# Is there a way to automate file/folder syncing if and when there is a change to specified files/folders?

Tags: windows, sync, dropbox

Right now I have a Dropbox Folder synced to another folder on my hard drive and to one on my external hard drive. I have done this by using Sync Toy and a scheduled event that fires every 30 minutes.

However this seems somewhat wasteful to me as it really only needs to run as soon as a file is changed in either the folder on my hard drive or the drop box folder (external hard drive is simply used as a backup).

Is there a way to fire the scheduled event on folder/file change in either location? Or is there an easier way of going about the same task?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dropbox Folder Sync](http://satyadeepk.in/dropbox-folder-sync/)

> Dropbox Folder Sync is a simple app for Dropbox that allows you to
>   seamlessly sync folders outside the Dropbox folder. Pretty handy for
>   syncing Firefox profiles, saved games, music library, Outlook data
>   files etc.,  to Dropbox directly from their locations. Sync and Unsync
>   to Dropbox just by using the right click menu on the folder. It
>   actually works by moving the folder into Dropbox and then putting a
>   symlink in its place.
>
> If you are new to Dropbox, it is a popular file synchronization and
>   backup tool which automatically syncs all your devices to the cloud.
>   You can also share and collaborate on your stuff with others. It also
>   offers you 2 GB of free online storage. (Get Dropbox or Know more).
>
> But one limitation of Dropbox is that, it will only sync the files in
>   your Dropbox folder. Our app helps to overcome this limitation by
>   allowing any folder to sync with Dropbox right from its location.